# Array of String to display String in java

Tags: java

```
package helloworld;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Random;

public class conn {

    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "Jambone1";
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static Connection con;
    private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/students?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        String[] name1 = {"HARRY" ,"JACK" ,"THOMAS", "ALFIE ","RILEY",
         "JAMES", "JOSHUA", "ETHAN", "SAMUEL", "DANIEL",
         };
        Random ran = new Random();

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("done");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            String name;

            int salary = 100;
            int batchSize = 10;
            for (int i = 1; i <= batchSize; i++) {
                String insert = "INSERT INTO e(nr,name,salary) VALUES('" + i + 
                  "','" + name1 + "','" + salary + "')";
                stmt.addBatch(insert);
            }
            int[] results = stmt.executeBatch();
            System.out.println((results));
            con.commit();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("did not work--> " + e);
        } finally {
            con.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the code save names in the database using this code. I send to database but not the names. This code adds to the database but I want the names to randomize and it shows not saved as number but as names in the database.

Comment: probably `name1` should be `name1[i-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `preparedStatement`

```
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
String stmt = "INSERT INTO e (nr, name, salary,) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

for( i = 0 ; i < batchSize; i++ ) {
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(stmt);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, name1[i]);
    preparedStatement.setDouble(3, salary);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I edited your code formatting to make it more readable. If you want to make my name disappear off the answer just make another edit.

Comment: okay now i need a way where i can randomise the string for a million times and more

Comment: okay now i need a way where i can randomise the string for a million times and more